# JComboBox border. How to remove?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, border, jcombobox

How do you take away the blue border that comes as default on a JComboBox component? 
I've tried:

```
playlist1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776893/remove-border-from-jcombobox

Comment: depends of if is editable or not